# Google Toolbar Bookmark - Labelled yet aslo appear at the folder root

Tags: label, google-bookmarks, google-toolbar

I've been using the fabulous Bookmark feature in the Google toolbar. The labelling of the bookmark allows the bookmark to appear in more than one label-folder.

I am wondering if I can label a bookmark to appear both in the root (default for no label) as well as inside at least one other label-folder. One may ask why do you need to 'hide' it in another folder when it is in the root. My reason is simple, I want to label everything for the sake of organization.

Comment: Guess creating duplicate bookmarks is out of the question?

Comment: Well, even if it works, it defeats the purpose of ease of management. Nice advice tho :P

Comment: You are talking about Chrome right? Or Chromium?

Comment: @eight: No, I'm refering to Google Toolbar's Bookmark feature (For Firefox, IE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK bookmarks that appear at the root are unlabeled.

You could create a label named 'All' and assign it to all bookmarks, thus creating one folder that contains all bookmarks.

Comment: Not a 100% ideal solution but at least it offers something. I'll accept this :)